# Powershell not able to clear IE Browsing Cookies, Caches, etc

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, browser, scripting

I am trying to clear browser data from default location **C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache**. I am trying to clear Cookies, Cache or any type files located in that path but I am not sure what am I missing here

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBeWm.png)

```
Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow "#######################################################"
""
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Powershell commands to delete cache & cookies in Firefox, Chrome & IE browsers"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "By Cesar Silva"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "VERSION: 3"
""
Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow "#######################################################"
""
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "CHANGE_LOG:
v2.4: - Resolved *.default issue, issue was with the file path name not with *.default, but issue resolved
v2.3: - Added Cache2 to Mozilla directories but found that *.default is not working
v2.2: - Added Cyan colour to verbose output
v2.1: - Added the location 'C:\Windows\Temp\*' and 'C:\`$recycle.bin\'
v2:   - Changed the retrieval of user list to dir the c:\users folder and export to csv
v1:   - Compiled script"
""
Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow "#######################################################"
""
#########################
"-------------------"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "SECTION 1: Getting the list of users"
"-------------------"
# Write Information to the screen
Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow "Exporting the list of users to c:\users\%username%\users.csv"
# List the users in c:\users and export to the local profile for calling later
dir C:\Users | select Name | Export-Csv -Path C:\users\$env:USERNAME\users.csv -NoTypeInformation
$list=Test-Path C:\users\$env:USERNAME\users.csv
""
#########################
"-------------------"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "SECTION 2: Beginning Script..."
"-------------------"
if ($list) {
    "-------------------"
    # Clear Internet Explorer
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "SECTION 5: Clearing Internet Explorer Caches"
     "-------------------"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow "Clearing Google caches"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor cyan
    Import-CSV -Path C:\users\$env:USERNAME\users.csv | foreach {
        Remove-Item -path "C:\Users\$($_.Name)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\*.*" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        Remove-Item -path "C:\Users\$($_.Name)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\*" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        Remove-Item -path "C:\Users\$($_.Name)\AppData\Local\Temp\*" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        Remove-Item -path "C:\Windows\Temp\*" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        Remove-Item -path "C:\`$recycle.bin\" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
            }

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow "Done..."
    ""
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "All Tasks Done!"
    } else {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Session Cancelled"  
    Exit
    }
```

Comment: You're missing the fact that IE doesn't use "flat" file system storage to store those items. Clearing these items requires API calls rather than just deleting files from some directories. IIRC you can configure clearing these items using GPOs.

Comment: I'm in favor of Bender's answer. You could check if there's any error first with removing `-EA SilentlyContinue`. Besides, Bender's answer can work well on my side.

Answer (score 1):

Well if any errors are occurring, you are suppressing them with the `-EA SilentlyContinue` flag. I would remove that from your `Remove-Item` calls and see if any sneaky errors are hiding there.

I'm not sure if you intended this, but in your first `Remove-Item` call under `INetCache`:

```
Remove-Item -path "C:\Users\$($_.Name)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\*.*"
```

You are removing only files with a `.` in the filename, basically only files with extensions. If you want to remove everything from that directory regardless of whether it has a file extension, just use `*` instead of `*.*` as you do for your other paths.